# How to add GPIImage filters to Twilio video call

Tags: twilio, swift4, gpuimage

I need to add GPUImage filters to the video call (Twilio) using swift 4.
Is there any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by using screen capture "share screen"
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/ios-v1-screen-capture
nested of video call

Comment: I am trying to make a video call but i want to send a greyscale video. Can i do that with Twilio?? (Android and iOS)

Comment: How it is possible to add Filter using Screen Capture.? 
Screen Capture is usually for share your iOS screen with other Participants connected to a Room using ReplayKit.framework.